# Is there any other method like OnNavigatedTo?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, navigation

Am using OnNavigatedTo for passing values while navigating between page, am getting the values in OnNavigatedTo.

That is working fine and now the problem is,

For sample i have screen A, B and C.
When i send data from A to B i can able to collect data in B.
So B has OnNavigatedTo method, when i navigate from B to C and come back to B OnNavigatedTo is called once when i come back to screen B.

Can some one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use static variables, or better - use MVVM: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your OnNavigatedTo handler of screen B, you can check whether the navigation is backwards or a fresh navigation

```
if (e.NavigationMode != System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
{
    //Navigation is not backwards
    //Your code
}
```